# Update one spreadsheet based on another by worksheet?

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet, spreadsheet A, with worksheets 'daily totals', 'weekly totals', and 'monthly totals'. The way these worksheets are populated is by taking information from another spreadsheet, spreadsheet B, that has the same tabs and headers and simply appending it to spreadsheet A after the last row under the corresponding tab.

This is currently done manually and I'm looking for a method that accomplishes this same task in a more automated manner.

Comment: An automated process needs to be smart....How do we know if sheet-B has been done? Is B empty, because the rows were CUT instead of copied? Or is a cell on B updated to mark it as done? What prevents B from being appended to sheet-A a second time? Is some paper record kept outside the two sheets? Or before "taking" the info, does one have to check sheet-A to ensure that B hasn't been copied already? These answers need to be incorporated into automated solution. Share these with us, and we may come up with something.

Comment: @donPablo These are very excellent points that I failed to acknowledge. I have to determine a way that spreadsheet A will not copy the same data multiple times from spreadsheet B. Maybe a cell should be modified indicating the data has already been copied over. I'm not an Excel pro, so I'm not entirely sure this could be done within the program.

Comment: What method is used now?

Comment: @donPablo Everything is done manually at the moment. We have a master spreadsheet which contains the history of aggregated data and a separate spreadsheet that gets updated with the data that ultimately goes into the master spreadsheet. I'm not even sure where to begin really.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just setting the cell that contains the data you want populated equal to the cell where the data is contained? This will work even if the data is in another worksheet or workbook.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I'm not so sure that would work. I'm sure I explained this poorly, so I apologize. Spreadsheet A will constantly be appending data, taking the latest data from spreadsheet B and adding after the last row. The next time, B will contain entirely new data (replacing the old set) and spreadsheet A should then take that data and append it once more in the fashion described above.

Comment: Definitely can be done...but SO would be the place where you have code written and we can critique/correct it, not write it from the start. Do you have something written that we can look at?